# Routing with slug and id with dash separated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

```
router->get('{slug}-{id}', 'Controller@method');
router->get('{otherSomething}', 'Controller@method2');
```

this is my routing and first line doesn't work. how to fix it? my software specification does not allow use slash (/) instead dash (-) in first routing.

for router below samples have the same mask

```
site.com/slug-name-and-sth-100
site.com/other-something
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Because this should work fine.

Comment: Try with '{id}-{slug}' instead

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `other-something` doesn't end with number, you can use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) , for example you can define route with id like this:

```
$router->get('{slug}-{id}', 'Controller@method')->where('id','[0-9]+');
```

and now it should work. However you need to remember to put this route before the route:

```
$router->get('{otherSomething}', 'Controller@method2');
```

otherwise it won't work.

**EDIT**

In case both urls can have same format, you should remove `{slug}-{id}` route completely and direct all the traffic for `{otherSomething}` into one method (`method2` in your case).

Now you should parse the `$otherSomething` variable and decide what you should do:

- either you decide it's format `{slug}-{id}` na you can now run service for this
- either you will run other service for other cases

Comment: {otherSomething} can have number in the end unfortunatelly :>